# Boolean Return File exist for give File name returns only false where am I doing mistake

Tags: java, list, arraylist, file-io, collections

```
File f = new File("c:/Desktop/Folder");
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
File[] files = f.listFiles();
for(File fi : files()){
   if(fi.isFile())
       result.add(fi.getName());
}
(result.contains(name));

return new File(name+".txt").exists();
```

Comment: do you have `somefile.doc.txt`? why are you appending `.txt`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

new File() needs as parameter the full path c:/folder/somefile.txt
if the parameter is only "somefile.txt" java looks in the current working directory for the file.
You can get the current working directory by calling

```
System.gerProperty("user.dir");
```

Comment: For the given name I have to Canca."txt" and find if any file with the given name exits or not if exists I have to return boolean and name

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to return if the "c:/Desktop/Folder" directory contains a file named *name*.txt?

```
File f = new File("c:/Desktop/Folder");

File[] files = f.listFiles();

for (File fi : files) {
  if (fi.isFile() && fi.getName().equals(name + ".txt")) {
    return true;
  }
}

return false;
```